# How to insert a string on a specific line in a Sublime Text Plugin?

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext3

I have the following plugin that puts a time stamp at the top of the document on line 1 but I'd like it to insert the string on a different line, like line 6. At first I thought the insert method was 0 indexed but that doesn't seem to be the case. How would I tell the `insert` method which line to insert the `signature` string at?

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import datetime, getpass

class SignatureCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        signature = "[%s]\n" % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %B %d %I:%M %p"))
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, signature)
```

Thanks for your help :)

**Update**: thanks to Enteleform for the wonderful answer, I added a `line_num` variable for added clarity :)

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import datetime, getpass

class SignatureOnSpecificLineCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        line_num = 6 # line number that signature will go on
        signature = "[%s]\n" % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %B %d %I:%M %p"))
        line6_column0 = self.view.text_point(line_num - 1, 0)
        self.view.insert(edit, line6_column0, signature)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view.insert()` takes a `point` as it's location argument.

Points are essentially sequential character positions within a document.

---

For example, in the following document:

```
Hello
World
```

a caret at the end of `World` would be at point `11`

- 5 characters in `Hello`
- 1 `NewLine` character after `Hello`
- 5 characters in `World`

---

In order to calculate the point of a particular row & column, use:

`view.text_point(row, column)`

---

#### Example:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import datetime, getpass

class SignatureCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        signature = "[%s]\n" % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %B %d %I:%M %p"))
        line = 6
        point = self.view.text_point(line - 1, 0)
        self.view.insert(edit, point, signature)
```

---

#### Note:

`rows` start at `0` and thus are offset from the displayed `lines` in SublimeText by `-1`, which is why I included `line - 1` in `view.text_point()`

Comment: Cool! Thanks so much :) this was exactly what I was looking for. I also went ahead and added a `line_num` variable that can be adjusted later.

Comment: @mbigras : Good call, I updated the answer to reflect that since it offers improved usability.